# Multiple ethernet device to single laptop

Tags: ethernet, webcam, camera, ip-camera

I am working on a project in which I have to connect multiple webcams to my PC through an ethernet cable. Is there any device which can help in accomplishing this task. How is there any other way through which I can connect multiple cameras to my PC. if yes, then do I have to perform some extra configuration inside the Operating system, for example, how can I select which camera is under use or how to display stream all cameras. btw I am using Linux.

Comment: I suppose that if everything is ethernet, you will need a switch.

Comment: @jcbermu is a single switch is sufficient or i have to perform some extra configuration?

Comment: It's highly recommendable that the switch supports gigabit ethernet. You have to be sure that the *PC - Switch* connection is in gigabit, to avoid bottlenecks.

Comment: Do you know the bandwith of the camera's streams? Most of them let you select different streams qualities. You need to select a quality that doesn't hog all the available bandwith.

Comment: @jcbermu yes I can adjust the resolution and framerate, but I want to ask that whether I just need to connect all the cameras to ethernet switch or I have to perform some extra configuration inside the Operating system for example, how can I select which camera is under use or how to display stream all camerss. btw I am using Linux.

Comment: You need [zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/downloads) to control the cameras.

Answer (score 0):

A switch that supports gigabit ethernet, so the *switch-PC* connection is stablished on gigabit to avoid bottlenecks on the point where all the camera streams will get together.

On Linux the application [zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/downloads) will give you a complete surveillance solution allowing capture, analysis, recording and monitoring. Zoneminder use the Video For Linux (V4L) interface and supports most IP network cameras.